# Display common values in two tables that are not present in the third table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The three tables in question are:

Table A - relevant columns are TimeTicket and IdAddress
Table B - relevant columns are CommunicationNumber, TimeCreate and IdAddress. 
Table C - relevant columns are CommunicationNumber, LastCalled, NextCall

Table C is created by a join of TableA and TableB on IdAddress

```
INSERT INTO tblC ([CommunicationNumber], [LastCalled] ,[NextCall])
SELECT T2.CommunicationNumber, T2.TimeCreate, T1.TimeTicket
FROM tblA T1
INNER JOIN tblB T2
ON T1.IdAddress = T2.IdAddress AND T2.CommunicationNumber IS NOT NULL
```

That's one part of the process, and that's fine.

Now, when there is new data in Table A and Table B, I want to update the data entries in Table C. However, I want to ignore the values from Table A and Table B that I have already entered into Table C.

To achieve this, I used NOT EXISTS and wrote a query that looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO tblC ([CommunicationNumber], [LastCalled] ,[NextCall])
SELECT T2.CommunicationNumber, T2.TimeCreate, T1.TimeTicket
FROM tblA T1
INNER JOIN tblB T2
ON T1.IdAddress = T2.IdAddress AND T2.CommunicationNumber IS NOT NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT T3.CommunicationNumber
                    FROM [dbo].[tblPhoneLogRep] T3
                    WHERE T1.TimeTicket <> T3.NextCall AND T2.TimeCreate <> T3.LastCalled AND T2.CommunicationNumber <> T3.CommunicationNumber)
```

However, this query always returns an empty set.

Could someone please explain to me what is it that I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `EXCEPT` set operator:

```
INSERT INTO tblC ([CommunicationNumber], [LastCalled] ,[NextCall])
SELECT T2.CommunicationNumber, T2.TimeCreate, T1.TimeTicket
FROM tblA T1
INNER JOIN tblB T2
ON T1.IdAddress = T2.IdAddress AND T2.CommunicationNumber IS NOT NULL
EXCEPT
SELECT CommunicationNumber, LastCalled, NextCall FROM tblC
```

To fix your existing query, you would need to change your `<>` operators to `=` operators, like so:

```
INSERT INTO tblC ([CommunicationNumber], [LastCalled] ,[NextCall])
SELECT T2.CommunicationNumber, T2.TimeCreate, T1.TimeTicket
FROM tblA T1
INNER JOIN tblB T2
ON T1.IdAddress = T2.IdAddress AND T2.CommunicationNumber IS NOT NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM tblC
                    WHERE T1.TimeTicket = tblC.NextCall AND T2.TimeCreate = tblC.LastCalled AND T2.CommunicationNumber = tblC.CommunicationNumber)
```

Personally, I think the `EXCEPT` syntax is more clear though.

Comment: I'd go with the EXCEPT version (the other one works as well). As you said, it just looks cleaner.

Comment: It looks like the EXCEPT query returns a DISTINCT on CommunicationNumber, could you explain why that is happening? Going with the other version for now.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are essentially using a double negative. You are saying `NOT EXISTS` and you are setting your `WHERE` criteria to `<>`. I think it would work out if you either used `EXISTS` or change you criteria `=`.